# Learning MVC and C# with the IController interface

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

I'm a 2nd year computer science student and have worked with Java during the entire course of the education so far. I'm now trying to play with C# to learn more about it by making a small program using the MVC structure following this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25057/Simple-Example-of-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Design

I'm using his basic structure (fitted to match my own neéds of course) but I'm having trouble understanding the IController interface? Visual studio don't seem to recognize the existence of this interface, even if I type in the path manually in the imports?

What am I missing? Why can't I use the IController interface in Visual Studio 2013? I see the documentation is there on microsofts page so it should exist.. I feel like I'm missing something ridicolously obvious?

Comment: Have you included the System.Web.Mvc assembly in the project, and put 'using System.Web.Mvc' at the top of the source file?  Otherwise, can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add "using System.Web.Mvc" to the top of your file.

And also:

Go to your menu: Project > Add Reference... > Browse.

Then browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies

Pick the latest version of MVC in the ASP.NET folder (or whichever one you want to use).

Comment: As I already mentioned I tried declaring it in the imports like you said, but Visual Studio just writes the Mvc part of the declaration in red and shows suggestions indicating the mvc part doesn't exist at all...?

Comment: Ah I see - sorry my misunderstanding (no coffee yet).

Looks like you need to add a reference to Mvc. If you're using the sample project from that website then that's likely the cause.

Go to your menu: Project > Add Reference... > Browse.


Then browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies

Pick the latest version of MVC in the ASP.NET folder (or whichever one you want to use).